# Correct way to replace Django Model class with an equivalent+decorated subclass

Tags: django, django-models

I'm writing a decorator intended to add functionality to decorated Django Model classes.  Something like this:

```py
class NewFunctionality:
   @classmethod
   def fun1(cls):
      ...

   @property
   def prop1(self):
      ...

def add_functionality(Decorated):
   class NewClass(Decorated, NewFunctionality):
      class Meta(getattr(Decorated, 'Meta', object)):
        app_label = Decorated._meta.app_label

   NewClass.__name__ = Decorated.__name__
   NewClass.__doc__ = Decorated.__doc__
   return NewClass


@add_functionality
class MyModel(models.Model):
   ...
```

This seems to work until there are two decorated model classes, when I get an error `Conflicting 'modelclass' models in application 'my_app'`.

This is apparently due to the registry of models that Django keeps, which clearly has some automagic that doesn't appreciate new model classes being made, even if they are direct replacements of the existing one.

Is there anything I can do to accomplish this, other than by monkeypatching the decorated class, adding each needed method?

#### Edit

I've avoided the error by making the wrapper class into a proxy class of the decorated class:

```
def add_functionality(Decorated):
   class NewClass(Decorated, NewFunctionality):
      class Meta(getattr(Decorated, 'Meta', object)):
        app_label = Decorated._meta.app_label
        proxy = True

   NewClass.__name__ = Decorated.__name__
   NewClass.__doc__ = Decorated.__doc__
   return NewClass
```

I also replace the use of the `class` keyword, using `builtins.type`, as in:

```
def add_functionality(Decorated):
   return type(
       Decorated.__name__,
       (NewFunctionality, Decorated,),
       {
           'Meta': type('Meta', (object,), {
                'app_label': Decorated._meta.app_label,
                'proxy': True,
           '__module__': Decorated.__module__,
       }
   )
```

I really like this as it seemingly completely replaces the decorated class.  Now, however, I'm getting the following warning from Django:

```
.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:321
  /home/tyler/orm-cache/django-ormsgpack/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:321: RuntimeWarning: Model 'my_app.atestmodel' was already registered. Reloading models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most notably with related models.
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
```

If anyone can shed light onto how I might utilize the Django api to properly overwrite the registered model, I'd love to hear it!

thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be more simple to define abstract class or mixin for that purpose?

Comment: @AlexeyPopov yeah I started out that way but I want to be able to execute code that introspects the class being modified, and I can't add a metaclass because Django models already provide one.  Unless I'm misunderstanding metaclasses in some way?  So if I have to then I will use a hybrid of decorator+mixin, but I thought I'd just take a little detour and perhaps learn something new.

If you have any ideas how I can apply two metaclasses or somehow otherwise inspect the model class at the time that the mixin is being applied, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You can define your custom base model class with modified Meta and in your models inherit Meta from it

Here is the docs on the subject: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance


But I'm not sure I get the whole idea. What goal exactly you're trying to achieve?